# Sum and difference between columns based on an ID in dplyr R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

My data frame looks like this

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,2), mean=c(0.5,0.6), sd=c(0.1,0.2))

  id mean  sd
1  1  0.5 0.1
2  1  0.6 0.2
3  2  0.5 0.1
4  2  0.6 0.2
```

I want to create a column, outcome, where I sum(mean +sd) for id==1 and I find the difference between mean-sd for id==2.

The desired outcome should be something like this

```
  id mean  sd  outcome
1  1  0.5 0.1    0.6
2  1  0.6 0.2    0.8
3  2  0.5 0.1    0.4
4  2  0.6 0.2    0.4
```

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df %>% mutate(
    outcome = case_when(
      id ==1 ~ mean + sd,
      id == 2 ~  mean - sd

    )
  )

  id mean  sd outcome
1  1  0.5 0.1     0.6
2  1  0.6 0.2     0.8
3  2  0.5 0.1     0.4
4  2  0.6 0.2     0.4
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use `ifelse` -

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(outcome = ifelse(id == 1,  mean + sd , mean - sd))

#  id mean  sd outcome
#1  1  0.5 0.1     0.6
#2  1  0.6 0.2     0.8
#3  2  0.5 0.1     0.4
#4  2  0.6 0.2     0.4
```

`mean - sd` will be applied to all `id`'s apart from 1, so if you have more than 2 id's and want to apply a different condition to them you may use nested `ifelse` or `case_when` as shown in @maydin's answer.

Comment: Thank you so much Ronak. Always so neat answers

Answer (score 1):

We can also do

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, outcome := fifelse(id == 1, mean + sd, mean = sd)]
```